# what does FFd1 mean in VHDL Warning FF/Latch has a constant value of 0

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm trying to implement a finite state machine identifier with xilinix 10.1
I've seen those errors in previous questions but the answers didn't include my question.. I'm not searching for an answer but rather a meaning for the FFd1 part

The following error is generated

```
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <machine1/current_state_FFd1> has a constant value of 0 in block <Main>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
WARNING:Xst:1293 - FF/Latch <machine1/current_state_FFd2> has a constant value of 0 in block <Main>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

this is my code

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;


entity M_1 is
    Port ( x : in  STD_LOGIC;
       clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
       state : out  integer range 0 to 5 := 0;
       z : out  STD_LOGIC );
end M_1;

architecture Behavioral of M_1 is

 type state_type is (A, B, C, D);
 signal next_state, current_state: state_type := A;

begin

process(clk) is
begin
if (clk = '1' and clk'event) then
    current_state <= next_state;
end if;
end process;

process(x,current_state)
begin
case current_state is
    when A =>
        if(x='0') then
            next_state <= B;
            z <='0';
        elsif(x='1') then
            next_state <= C;
            z <='1';            
        end if;
    when B =>
        if(x='0') then
            next_state <= C;
            z <='1';
        elsif(x='1') then
            next_state <= D;
            z <='0';            
        end if;
    when C =>
        if(x='0') then
            next_state <= A;
            z <='0';
        elsif(x='1') then
            next_state <= D;
            z <='1';            
        end if;
    when D =>
        if(x='0') then
            next_state <= B;
            z <='0';
        elsif(x='1') then
            next_state <= C;
            z <='0';            
        end if;
    end case;
end process;

process (current_State) is
begin
    case current_state is
    when A =>
        state <=0;
    when B =>
        state <=1;
    when C =>
        state <=2;
    when D =>
        state <=3;
    end case;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

can anyone tell me

- What does current_state_FFd1 and what's the difference between it and current_State_1 ?
- how can i solve this error ?

Thanks inadvance

Comment: The message means the current_state signal never changes, so it will be optimized away. There's not enough code to know why this happens but it's probably because clk is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "current_state" signal is mapped onto a 2-bit flip-flop primitive by the CAD tools. The flip-flop will look something like [the FD16CE primitive, shown here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_2/virtex6_scm.pdf#page=165).

The flip-flop will take 2 data inputs (current_state_FFd1 and current_state_FFd2) and a clock, and produce two data outputs (current_state_FFq1 and current_state_FFq2). The inputs determine the value of the current_state signal sampled at the next clock edge, and the outputs reflect the current state.

The message you're seeing suggests that the CAD tools can prove that "current_state" never changes from the "00" encoding ("A" in your enumerated type), and so the flip-flop can be optimized away with a hard-wired output of "00".

The VHDL you posted looks reasonable -- changes on the 'x' input should cause a change in current_state. I'll bet the 'x' input is somehow hard-wired to 0 in higher-level VHDL (or in your testbench.)